# Laravel update one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I have a request that contains the next data

```
{
  "path": "some path",
  "site_link": "http://example.com"  
  "features": [ ... ] //array of strings
}
```

I wish to update my two tables `site` and `site features`.

`site` table contains `| id | path | site_link |`.

And `site features` these `| id | feature | site_id |`
I don't know exact amount of "features" however I need to update them after request.

Is there any way to update them **except** for delete and then create once again. (some features may be changed, some be deleted and be added).

For now I don't have any code for updating features. Only this

```
public function update(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
        $site->update([
            "path" => $request->path,
            "site_link" => $request->link
        ]);

        return response()->json($site, 200);
    }
```

Comment: are you store features in each row ? or just storing them in one row ?

Comment: of course in each row. otherwise I wouldn't create this table

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your situation you can't update your site_features rows something like that. Because you need to second identifier in your site_features table. Below query updates only first column again and again. So, only way to save these features `create` new rows with create method.

İf you want to update specific site_features column, you have to pass ids of those features to controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
       // first you need to select a row before updating it
        $site = $site->where("site_link",$request->site_link)->first(); 
        $site->update([
            "path" => $request->path,
           ]);

        foreach($request->features as $feature){
            SiteFeature::where("id",$feature->id)
             ->update([
                "feature" => $feature->content
             ]);
          }

        return response()->json($site, 200);
    }
```

If you don't have id parameter yet, if these are new features then you have to create new records about them

```
public function update(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
        $site = $site->where("site_link",$request->site_link)->first(); 
        $site->update([
            "path" => $request->path,
           ]);

        foreach($request->features as $feature){
            SiteFeature::create([
                "feature" => $feature
             ]);
          }

        return response()->json($site, 200);
    }
```

And, there third way to this. If your features are limited. For example, there are only 80 features about these websites. Some websites have some features and others not.. Then you may want to use `many to many` relationship. Create features table and add all features, and make many to many to relationship between features and sites. After that, you only need to sync these features. It's very easy to use. And also when you need to some changes about one of the feature. You don't have do mass changes. Just change this feature on features table then this effect all websites.

I hope you understand me, because my english is so awfull :)

Comment: FIrstly, I've I do have `SiteFeature` model. Secondly, they are spread over any amount of rows they need. Only one feature per row

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all hope you've created a model for site-features table. It's pretty easy.
Now after this

```
$updates =  SiteFeatures :: where ('feature',$feature)->where('site_id',$siteID) ->get();
```

for Updation:-

```
$updates->feature = $newFeature;
$updates->save();
```

for Deletion:-

```
$updates->delete();
```

for Addition of new feature you don't need the first statement 
instead

```
$newFeature = new SiteFeatures();
$newFeature->feature = 'the new feature';
$newFeature->site_id = the_site_id;
$newFeature->save();
```